# How to refresh/reload an imported file on python after making changes inside that file

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to refresh perhaps reload the whole file I imported on a script in which I used to changed some things within that file, and using that script to reload the file I imported within itself.

How do I refresh a file which is a script that has been imported as a module after making changes on it using the script which contains that imported file.

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
#lists_values.py
Christine = [0,0,0]
George = [900,123,1]
#suppose Ralf = [ 0, 0, 0 ] is going at     this position soon.

#main.py
from lists_values import *
import lists_values

def insertRalf():
    with open("lists_values.py", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("Ralf = [0, 0, 0]\n")

insertRalf()

def resultView():
    #Maybe some code to refresh the file I imported? Which is the lists_value since I added another list I want to print it.

    #Print the NEW values of lists_values
    fd = open("lists_values.py", "r")
    print(fd.read())
    fd.close()
     #My goal is to see the new value 'Ralf', but since I imported the file when it was still unchanged, I wont see any Ralf if I print it now.

resultView()
```

Comment: generally you don't want to do that, you'd store `Christine`, `George` and `Ralf` in a dictionary (or similar) and just update the object directly...  why write to a file and reload?  reloading is normally discouraged and only used out of convenience to a developer that has externally modified the code

Comment: is there any way to store them in a dictionary to make these value stay there when I run the code once again?

Comment: define "stay there"!  taking a guess, why not just use the `json` module to load/save them to another file?  there are lots of other file formats around for this, e.g. csv files or full blown relational databases

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are better ways to do what you want!

You appear to be using the `values` module as some sort of namespace. It would be much more sensible to store only the data in some file. If you read the documentation for the [`shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shelve.html) you will see that for simple values and string keys it acts, within limits, as a sort of dictionary-on-disk.

Putting names in a Python namespace dynamically is a "code smell" - since you never know what names will be defined, you also end up having to access them dynamically with `getattr` or similar tedious stuff.